# How do I call a class into another with different parameters?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, random, insertion-sort

I'm unsure how do I call my code so that it matches my randomizer. My randomizer basically generates a number of random integers in an array and prints them like so.

**Edit: If i wasn't clear, i want to call my randomizer into both the methods of the insertion sort class!**

I tried using the insertion sort implementation i grabbed from geeks4geeks. They all have the parameter int[arr].

This is my code

```
public class randomArr {

    public void randomizer(){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random r = new Random();

        System.out.println("Please enter the amount of integers you want in your array: ");
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        // Create array of 1000 ints
        int[] intArr = new int[n];

// Fill array with random ints
        for ( int i = 0; i < intArr.length; i++) {
            intArr[i] = r.nextInt(100);
            System.out.print(intArr[i] + ", ");
        }

    }

}
```

This is what i want to happen basically:

As you can see im calling sort and print array with my "intArr". How do i call my method with the given methods?

I have commented out the object i made using my method but if i were to leave it in, how would i use that object to call sort() and printarray()?

```
public class insertionSort {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        //randomArr arry = new randomArr(); \\the object of my method
        //arry.randomizer());

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random r = new Random();

        System.out.println("Please enter the amount of integers you want in your array: ");
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        // Create array of 1000 ints
        int[] intArr = new int[n];

// Fill array with random ints
        for ( int i = 0; i < intArr.length; i++) {
            intArr[i] = r.nextInt(100);
            System.out.print(intArr[i] + ", ");
        }
        sort(intArr);
        printArray(intArr);
    }


        public static void sort(int arr[]){
            int n = arr.length;
            for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
                int key = arr[i];
                int j = i - 1;

            /* Move elements of arr[0..i-1], that are
               greater than key, to one position ahead
               of their current position */
                while (j >= 0 && arr[j] > key) {
                    arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
                    j = j - 1;
                }
                arr[j + 1] = key;
            }
        }
        static void printArray(int arr[]){
            int n = arr.length;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
                System.out.print(arr[i] + ", ");

            System.out.println();
        }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? Do you want to use the intArr generated in the randomArr class or you want to call the randomizer() method of that class in your insertionSort class?

Comment: @MananAdhvaryu I want to call the randomizer() method into the insertionSort class. Sorry I didnt know how to word that properly. Which i did (i commented that out) how do i call the randomizer with the sort method and the print array method from the insertionSort class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok if you want to call the method of one class into another, you simply need to call it by adding the methods name next to the object of that class with a period in between like so ("object.method()"). So what you would do is:

```
import java.util.*;
class randomArr {

    public int[] randomizer()
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random r = new Random();

        System.out.println("Please enter the amount of integers you want in your array: ");
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        // Create array of 1000 ints
        int[] intArr = new int[n];

// Fill array with random ints
        for ( int i = 0; i < intArr.length; i++) {
            intArr[i] = r.nextInt(100);
            System.out.print(intArr[i] + ", ");
        }

        return intArr;

    }

}

class Stack
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        randomArr rArr = new randomArr();
        int[] intArr = rArr.randomizer();
    }
}
```

this way you can make that array in your other class and use it in your new class.

If you want to call the methods of insertionSort class you can call them without an object since they are static. You cannot use the object of another class to call a method not belonging to that object's class.

You can use insertionSort's methods in the randomArr class by creating it's object in the randomArr class and vice versa. But an object can only access the methods of it's own class.

Comment: @Jordles let me know if this is what you wanted. If you have any doubt, I'm happy to help.

Comment: yes i did that already, I commented it out on my code above. The problem is how do i call the sort method and print array?

Comment: @Jordles do you want to use the "arry" object to call the methods of insertionSort class?

Comment: yes thats what im trying to say xD, wait im not sure. I'm trying to use randomizer and grabbing that random array and put that into the methods of insertionSort class. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes! Thanks so much! I get it now. My method didn't have anything to output from for the methods of insertionSort. Im confused on why i need create a new array (int [] intArr) and set that to my randomizer if my method is already "return intArr". Can't I do sort(rArr.randomizer()) <<<is this allowed?

Comment: @Jordles Yes! you can do that directly, I showed it that way to demonstrate how to use the output.

Answer (score 0):

you want to call method in another class you can create object of that class and then using the object reference you can call  available the methods  from that class.

```
insertionSort object = new insertionSort();
object.sort(intArr);
object.printArray(intArr);
```

As you defined sort and printArry are static methods , you can directly invoke them in your main method.